# why com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync in onResume?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I looked into the Facebook SDK 3.0 to try and find out how to track installs coming from a Facebook campaign and saw this in the documentation:

> For the FB Android SDK 3.0, add the following to onResume() of each Activity in your app:
>       com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, YOUR_APP_ID);

I have 2 basic questions:

1. Why is this happening in every activity instead of in the launcher activity?
2. Why is this happening in the `onResume` method instead of `onStart`? Android recommends not doing things like this in the `onResume`.

***Edit*** - even though it's asynchronous doing this over and over seems stupid and un necessary

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both questions is that by including the call in the onResume() method of every Activity you're dealing with network failures at the time the user first starts the app. In other words, your app will try to publish the installation every time an Activity is shown in the foreground, not just when the first Activity is started.

From [Facebook Developers Mobile App Install Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/):

> This will allow the app to ping back the install event to Facebook when the user opens up the app for the first time, and again in the future if there is a network error. Our client code will stop sending installs once it acquires a success code from the server, and our back-end will only count the install a single time if it receives multiple hits for the same device

Comment: I stil don't understand why not to do this from `onStart` or even `onCreate`, there's no reason to do this over and over every time the Activity resumes

Comment: I agree, however the call is essentially a no-op (at least network wise) once the SDK has received a response from the server.

Comment: It's just to have a slightly better chance of detecting and avoiding network failures by trying once more when the app resumes.

Otherwise you'd have to wait for the user to close the app and start it over to try again, which would be a real trouble if the user just used the Home button instead of actually quitting.

However, as far as I know, if you absolutely don't want to do that onResume for whatever reason, you can do it onCreate and hope it works the first time. It's just not recommended.

Comment: "Does it require in each and every activity or we can place in start-up screen?

Comment: @chintan It doesn't **require** the call in each and every Activity. However, it **recommends** it, for the reasons explained above (dealing with loss of network when the app starts).